# Select multiple checkboxes and update the database using submit button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox

I have just finished small project on multiple checkboxes using ajax. But now i want to use submit button for filter option. So now after multiple checkboxes are selected and after sumbit button are clicked then only it should change in the phone database. Any help ? Thanks. 
Here is my code: 
Index.php

```
<script>


 function makeTable(data){
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
      var tbl_row = "",
          currRecord = this;

      $.each(this, function(k , v) {
        if(k==='model'){
          v = "<a href='content.php?id=" + currRecord['id'] +"'>" + v + "</a>";
        } else if (k==='price'){
          v = "<span class='price'>" + v + "</span>";
        }
        tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
      })
      tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
    })

    return tbl_body;
  }

  function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
    var opts = [];
    $checkboxes.each(function(){
      if(this.checked){
        opts.push(this.id);
      }
    });

    return opts;
  }


  function updatePhones(opts){
    if(!opts || !opts.length){
      opts = allBrands;
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "submit.php",
      dataType : 'json',
      cache: false,
      data: {filterOpts: opts},
      success: function(records){
        $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));
        updatePrices();
      }
    });
  }

  function subsidyIsValid(){
    var amount1 = $("#amount1").val(),
        amount2 = $("#amount2").val(),
        regex = /^\d+$/,
        inputValid = false;

    if(regex.test(amount1) && regex.test(amount2)){
      var newTotal = Number(amount1) + Number(amount2)
      $("#total").text(newTotal);
      inputValid = true;
    }

    return inputValid
  }

  function updatePrices(){
    var subsidyTotal = Number($("#total").text());

    $(".price").each(function(){
      var origVal = Number($(this).text())
      $(this).text(origVal - subsidyTotal)
    })
  }

 $("#submitFilter").on("click", function(){
    var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
    updatePhones(opts);
        })

  $("#apply").on("click", function(){
    if(subsidyIsValid()){
      $(this).prop("disabled", true);
      $(this).next().prop("disabled", false);
      updatePrices();
    } else {
      alert("Subsidy invalid!")
    }
  });

  $("#remove").on("click", function(){
    $("#amount1").val("");
    $("#amount2").val("");
    $("#total").text("0");
    $(this).prop("disabled", true);
    $(this).prev().prop("disabled", false);

    $checkboxes.trigger("change");
  });

  var allBrands = [];
  $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
    allBrands.push($(this)[0].id)
  })

  updatePhones();
  updatePrices();
</script>
```

Submit.php

```
<?php 
require 'Database.php';
#### TEMP SET NAMES FÜR UTF8 ###################################################
include 'Json.php';
  $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];
  $tmp = array();
  foreach ($opts as $opt) {
        $tmp[] = '"'.$opt.'"';
  }
         $query = 
      'SELECT mobile_phone.id, name, model, price FROM mobile_phone INNER JOIN brand ON brand_id = brand.id WHERE name IN ('.implode(",", $tmp).')';


  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $data   = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $data[] = $row;
  }

echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: So it should filter results ONLY after submit has been clicked?

Comment: yes only after submit it should update the database.I have created Submit button and try to call function updatePhones(opts) on onclick but its not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, remove this listener:

```
$checkboxes.on("change", function(){
    var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
    updatePhones(opts);
  });
```

You don't want to change data in table on checking of a checkbox but only after clicking submit button. I don't see any "Submit" button other than "Apply" that seems to have to do with subsidue options more than with filtering, so add a 'submit' first (actually just a button):

```
(...)
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="Nokia">
  <label for="Nokia">Nokia</label>
</div>
<button id="submitFilter">Filter</button>
(...)
```

Then throw what you had in checkbox listener to the onClick of submitFilter.

```
 $("#submitFilter").on("click", function(){
     var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
     updatePhones(opts);
 });
```

I updated the fiddle so it is more accurate to your needs. [Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nMP93/6/)

EDIT:

To open a new tab:

```
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Where url is obviously an url you want to open. You can also set it as form target and put the data you want to pass in a form, and make filter a submit.

Comment: I tried to do the same thing but its not working still. Its not filtering the data on filter button.

Comment: Hi i have made changes please check the changes in index.php according to you but still its not working :(

Comment: Check the updated fiddle. It does most of what you want to do except ajax communication.

Comment: Hi i have seen the updated fiddle but i dont find any changes from the previous code.Can you please tell me where you have made changes ? The fiddle is working but i dont know why its not working from my code

Comment: It is taking the IDs of chosen checkboxes and inserting them into table on submit. Previous submit had hardcoded insert. Just use mine, but instead of taking IDs of checkboxes just pass and print the ajax result like before. If it doesn't work, check the CONSOLE of a browser, it will show you errors.

Comment: Hi thank you very much now its working for me.Please I just need one more idea from you.If i want to keep the filter options and submit button on new page then when i filter the options and click on filter button then in this case new page should open with the updated database.Then in this case how it works ? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "new page". New tab? Refresh page? Go to the other page in same tab?

Comment: yes exactly a new tab. I want to separate the filter option with button on new tab and phone database on the other tab.So on 1 tab you will see filter option with filter button and once you click on the filter button it should open new tab with the updated database.

Comment: I updated the answer but that's not really connected to that question, you should look around and try some solutions. I don't think it's best way to do that.

Comment: Yes i will look around.But the only problem in this case is to maintain event state while separating the tab. But anyway Thanks @mareck i am new in this forum and dont have that repution to vote u.But definately ur answer help me lot.

Comment: You can do it by button near top of my answer. It'll mark the question as answered.

Comment: Hey @mareck i am trying with the tab option but no luck yet. I have posted this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23867859/multiple-checkbox-options-using-the-button-divide-into-tabs      Please if you know the solution let me know it will be very good learning for me and i am also trying the same.Thanks.

Comment: hey @mareck i did not find a solution yet for the tab option.Can you please help me in the same ?