# Multiple checkbox options using the button divide into tabs

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, tabs

Here is my updated code for index.php file.Now i think the problem is only in the tabs.Tabs are not showing properly.They are showing like a link.And i think the problem is only the naming convention now.

Index.php

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dashboards</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 5px;
      }
      margin : 5px;
    font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #fff;
}

body {
    margin : 10px;
    font: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial;
    padding: 0px;
    background: #fff;
}

#tab-links {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
    margin : 0;
    padding-bottom : 19px;
    padding-left : 10px;
}

#tab-links ul, #tab-links li    {
    display : inline;
    list-style-type : none;
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
}


#tab-links a:link, #tab-links a:visited {
    background : #E8EBF0;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    color : #666;
    float : left;
    font-size : small;
    font-weight : normal;
    line-height : 14px;
    margin-right : 8px;
    padding : 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    text-decoration : none;
}

#tab-links a:link.active, #menu a:visited.active    {
    background : #fff;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
    color : #000;
}

#tab-links a:hover  {
    color : #f00;
}


body.tabs #tab-links li#nav-1 a, 
body.tabs #tab-links li#nav-2 a {
    background : #fff;
    border-bottom : 1px solid #fff;
    color : #000;
}

#tab-links #subnav-1,
#tab-links #subnav-2 {
    display : none;
    width: 90%;
}

body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-1, 
body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-2 {
    display : inline;
    left : 10px;
    position : absolute;
    top : 95px;
}

body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-1 a, 
body.tabs #tab-links ul#subnav-2 a {
    background : #fff;
    border : none;
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc;
    color : #999;
    font-size : smaller;
    font-weight : bold;
    line-height : 10px;
    margin-right : 4px;
    padding : 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    text-decoration : none;
}

 #tab-links ul a:hover {
    color : #f00 !important;
}

#contents {
    background : #fff;
    border : 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top : none;
    clear : both;
    margin : 0px;
    padding : 15px;
}

     #phones {
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 15px 25px 0 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
      }

      #phones th {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #039;
        padding: 0px 1px;
        border-bottom: 12px solid #6678b1;
      }

      #phones td {
        border-bottom: 0px solid #ccc;
        color: #669;
        padding: 1px 1px;
      }

      #phones tbody tr:hover td {
        color: #009;
      }

      #filter {
        float:left;
      }

      fieldset{
        margin-top: 15px;
      }

      fieldset div{
        padding:0 0 5px 0;
      }

      .amount{
        width:50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

  <div class="tabs">
           <ul class="tab-links">
              <li id="nav-1"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
              <li id="nav-2"><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                <table id="phones">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>

                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                                    </table>
                    </div>

                    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder" checked>
        <label for="Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder">Anzahl_Fahrzeuge_mit_und_ohne_Bilder</label><br>

             <input type="checkbox" id="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis" checked>
        <label for="Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis">Fahrzeuge_ohne_Preis</label>
        <button id="submitFilter">Filter</button> 
      </div>
    </div>



        <script>
      function makeTable(data){
        var tbl_body = "";
        $.each(data, function() {
          var tbl_row = "",
              currRecord = this;

          $.each(this, function(k , v) {
            if(k==='model'){
              v = "<a href='content.php?id=" + currRecord['id'] +"'>" + v + "</a>";
            } else if (k==='price'){
              v = "<span class='price'>" + v + "</span>";
            }
            tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
          })
          tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";
        })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getPhoneFilterOptions() {
     var opts = [];
     $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
         if (this.checked) {
             opts.push($(this).attr("id"));
         }
     });

     return opts;
 }

      function updatePhones(opts){
        if(!opts || !opts.length){
          opts = allBrands;
        }

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));

          }
        });
      }    

            $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
     var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

     // Show/Hide Tabs
     $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

     // Change/remove current tab to active
     $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

     e.preventDefault();
 });

      $("#submitFilter").on("click", function () {
     var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
          updatePhones(opts);
          ("#tab2").show().siblings().hide();
 });


      var allBrands = [];
      $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(){
        allBrands.push($(this)[0].id)
      })

      updatePhones();

    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you want it to open new tab every time you filter? I think it is really bad design and your users will feel uncomfotable with this. What is your reason for this?

Comment: @mereck thanks for your reply. Actually for my project i have to design like this. Its company project so i cant design on my own way.They said they want to reduce the space.The problem i am facing in this is i am using Ajax and when i try to divide it into tabs i dont know how to maintain the Ajax state and my checkbox option select state. I have updated the code please check it

Comment: Maybe write checkbox states (checkbox states) to session or cookie, open nee tab, in new tab read them.

Comment: checkbox state but how can i pass the result of them to next tab(new page) ?

Comment: You open the new tab every time on clixking submit or just once and then update then the already opened tab?

Comment: no once i run the tab.php it should show by default all phone database results.And there will be edit button and once you click on the edit button it should go to next tab i.e Edit Phone Database tab. In this tab you will see the checkbox filter options.And filter button.Once u click on filter button it will go to phone database tab with filtered phone database resutls.So it will reduce my page space because instead of showing everything on 1 page i am dividing it.If i solve this issue there will be more like this tab menu i can add.

Comment: I lost you. Do you mean new BROWSER tab or just other page in same BROWSER tab?

Comment: just the other page in same BROWSER tab.

Comment: Why do you need ajax if you reload whole page anyway? Or what you intend to do is to create a tab panel (one page) with container that is switched on ajax requests?

Comment: for example consider this as a example:http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Tabs-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/#tab22     it should be something like this

Comment: So we have 2 tabs phone database tab and edit phone database tab.

Comment: I have used tabs.php and tabs1.php to divide into 2 tabs but i think we can form this into single php code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you do not need to store anything in session variables or cookies after all.

The [tutorial you linked](http://inspirationalpixels.com/tutorials/creating-tabs-with-html-css-and-jquery#step-html) explains how to do the tabs. You create two divs and show/hide them on the go. You can also create one div and two html files (one for each tab) that will contain the contents of the tabs (database and phone detail) and reload it with ajax. Up to you.

You don't need many new things over what you have right now. I get it that you already have working tabs and only want to know how to pass the data between them. To do that, just use the variable with chosen filters in the function that is responsible for showing the details tab and switch the html of table like you did before wtih `$('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));`

EDIT:

Your fiddle is very wrong. Fix your "ul" and "li" tags so they are proper. Close your other opened tags. Put index.php content outside of  tag. After you fix your html, look at attribute "class" of the tabs. It has to match properly with the selectors from jquery. Add containers for tab content:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
         <!-- your filter here -->
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <!-- your table here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

After that modify your jQuery. Add this (take a look at selectors!!! you have to either follow naming convention from example or change it everywhere):

```
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
     var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

     // Show/Hide Tabs
     $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

     // Change/remove current tab to active
     $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

     e.preventDefault();
 });
```

It'll for example prevent your site from reloading on clicking of a tab. Have in mind it will open you new tab when you click on it. If you want to open it on button click, add following code:

```
 $("#submitFilter").on("click", function () {
     var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
     ("#tab2").show().siblings().hide();
     updatePhones(opts);
 });
```

It will open second tab and update the table like last time. Make sure the table is inside tab content container(#tab2).

You can put it all in one file:

```
<html>
    <body>
       (...)
       <div class="tabs">
           <ul class="tab-links">
              <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Tab #1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#tab2">Tab #2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
                <!-- your filter here -->
           </div>
           <div id="tab2" class="tab">
                    <!-- your table here -->
           </div>
       </div>
       (...)
       <script>
       // your script here
           (...)
           $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
               var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

               // Show/Hide Tabs
               $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

               // Change/remove current tab to active
               $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

               e.preventDefault();
           });
           $("#submitFilter").on("click", function () {
              var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
              ("#tab2").show().siblings().hide();
              updatePhones(opts);
           });
           (...)
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```